# First steps with Selenium and jUnit - any good tutorials?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, testing, selenium, junit

Anyone knows a good tutorial for a beginner in `Selenium` and `jUnit` ?
I already have a background in `unit testing` and `acceptance testing` (**RSpec** and **Capybara** on **Rails 3**), and now I'm starting this new project with **JavaEE** and I'm looking for a quick start with both of this technologies.
Thanks.

Comment: I found TutorialsPoint very helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/index.htm + http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/index.htm. Also, for Selenium nothing beats their learn-by-example method on their own website - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm doing some extensive reading/research about this subject so I'll share the good articles/slidshows/books/answers I found:

- http://www.qaautomation.net/?cat=7 : I used this website & I thought it was pretty good (for Selenium anyway).
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html : just had a
  look & seems interesting
- [wakaleo: junit-kung-fu-getting-more-out-of-your-unit-tests](http://www.slideshare.net/wakaleo/junit-kung-fu-getting-more-out-of-your-unit-tests) : a great overview on some key JUnit features
- [Test-your-web-application-s-UI-with-JUnit-and-Selenium](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143430/Test-your-web-application-s-UI-with-JUnit-and-Sele)
- [testing-a-web-application-with-selenium-2/](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/testing-a-web-application-with-selenium-2/) : Selenium + JUnit
- [Selenium best practice](http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/)
- [You use JUnit so you want to know Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)
- [SO question: how-to-use-junit-and-hamcrest-together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569394/how-to-use-junit-and-hamcrest-together)
  (TBC) Be careful when using JUnit & Hamcrest together: if Hamcrest has a version greater or equal to 1.2, then you should use the junit-dep.jar. This jar has no hamcrest classes and therefore you avoid classloading problems.
- Moreover regarding Hamcrest, it states [on its google code page](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) that "Hamcrest it is not a testing library: it just happens that matchers are very useful for testing". Hence you may want to [look into FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) "whose mission is to simplify software testing".
- [SO question: junit-one-test-case-per-method-or-multiple-test-cases-per-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252187/junit-one-test-case-per-method-or-multiple-test-cases-per-method)
- [SO question: selenium-junit-tests-how-do-i-run-tests-within-a-test-in-sequential-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518314/selenium-junit-tests-how-do-i-run-tests-within-a-test-in-sequential-order)
- [tomek kaczanowscy's blog: author of "Practical Unit Testing" (see below)](http://kaczanowscy.pl/tomek/)
- This book came out recently (Published in 2012 vs lots of out-of-date books) & it looks very interesting: [Practical Unit Testing with TestNG and Mockito by Tomek Kaczanowski](http://practicalunittesting.com/)

Finally, you probably want to look at a mocking framework (ie. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/), [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org)):

- [SO question: what-are-mock-objects-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128148/what-are-mock-objects-in-java)
- [SO question: what-does-a-mocking-framework-do-for-me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095796/what-does-a-mocking-framework-do-for-me)
- http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/mockito-best-practices/

Comment: You may want to look at TestNG, seems better than JUnit from what I read

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use TestNG instead of JUnit. TestNG offers you more options and possibilites how to run your tests and in which order especially (something Junit can't).
Here some useful links.

- [TestNG Doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html),
- [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/) here you can find the first guides
- [SeleniumApi](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html)
- [CssSelectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) very usefull for finding elements without id/name, better than xpath

Hope that helps