# Java alternative code for C# Assert.IsTrue and Assert.AreEquals?

Tags: java, selenium, assert

In C#:

```
  Assert.IsTrue(NewPagePost.IsInEditMode(), ""wasn't in edit mode");

  Assert.AreEqual("Sample Page", NewPostPage.Title, "Title did not match");
```

What is the Java alternative for Assert.IsTrue and Assert.AreEqual ?

Is the below code right :

```
   Assert.assertTrue("wasn't in edit mode", NewPostPage.IsInEditMode());
   Assert.assertEquals("Sample Page,", NewPostPage.getTitle(),"Title did not match");
```

Comment: Java doesn't have a built-in `Assert` class.  Are you using JUnit?

Comment: No, I am using Selenium Webdriver..

Comment: I don't know anything about Selenium Webdriver.  It looks like you're asking about unit testing.  I think you probably want JUnit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577254/first-steps-with-selenium-and-junit-any-good-tutorials (even though it's closed, somebody posted some links anyway).

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.assertTrue("wasn't in edit mode", NewPostPage.IsInEditMode());
Assert.assertEquals("Sample Page,", NewPostPage.getTitle(),"Title did not match");
```

The above looks good.

You can rewrite the second statement as

```
Assert.assertTrue("Sample Page".equals(NewPostPage.getTitle()),"Title did not match");
```